# Azure "JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm"

Tags: node.js, azure, jwt, token, azure-authentication

Azure Static Web App (SWA) with integrated API. One of the step at backend API is to validate the Bearer Token with public key submitted in request headers:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");  // v 8.5.1
async function getMSPublicKey(misc)   // misc contains kid and tenantId, confirmed in F12 request header
{
    var vurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + misc.tenantId + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    const x1 = await fetch(vurl);
    const x2 = await x1.json();
    const x3 = await fetch(x2.jwks_uri);
    const k = await x3.json();
    return pkey = k.keys.find( k => k.kid === misc.kid).x5c[0];  // public key in the entry matching kid
}

var vmisc = JSON.parse(ac.req.headers["misc"]);
var publickey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + await getMSPublicKey(vmisc) + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

// next line is reported in AppTraces, Message = JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm
var payload = jwt.verify(theToken, publickey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });
// theToken is validated ok at jwt.io
```

It only occurs when deployed to Azure cloud, local Azure Static Web Apps emulator is all ok.

**Update**, Guess this is something about Azure cloud, particularly security. similar result on another package [Jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose), error only on Azure cloud.

**Update: found culprit** My original code was sending the token in under `Authorization` name. Azure log shows its read-in length is always 372 vs. 1239 tested in local emulator. After renaming it to something else like `mytoken`, all good! This is undocumented, reminder to everyone: avoid sensitive/reserved words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to be painless and work the same with less code on your end, it handles rotation, re-fetching of the public keys, as well as implements a complete applicable JWK selection algorithm for all known JWS algorithms. Also does not depend on a brittle `x5c[0]` JWK parameter.

```js
const jose = require('jose')

const JWKS = jose.createRemoteJWKSet(new URL(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${misc.tenantId}/discovery/v2.0/keys`))

// JWKS you keep around for subsequent verifications.

const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtVerify(jwt, JWKS)
```

Comment: Looks like `jwt` in `const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtVerify(jwt, JWKS)`  should be the Bearer Token which is `eyJ...`, got **JSON Web Key Set malformed**.

Comment: I have not noticed the url was the discovery endpoint value. Use the jwks_uri value in the URL constructor instead.

Comment: Works out great at local, but err at Azure cloud. Here are some stacks: `at getKtyFromAlg (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwks/local.js:17:19) 
JOSENotSupported: Unsupported "alg" value for a JSON Web Key Set at getKtyFromAlg (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwks/local.js:17:19) 
at async compactVerify (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jws/compact/verify.js:18:22) at async Object.jwtVerify (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/verify.js:9:22) 
at Array.filter (<anonymous>) `

Comment: `at RemoteJWKSet.getKey (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwks/remote.js:33:32) 
code: 'ERR_JOSE_NOT_SUPPORTED'`  Looks like there is something how Azure Cloud is operating, involving some API calls even it's Microsoft's own endpoint, maybe blocking.

Comment: Complete code: `async function forJose(misc)
{
    var vurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + misc.tenantId + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    const x1 = await fetch(vurl);
    const x2 = await x1.json();
    return x2.jwks_uri;
}
const joseURL = await forJose(vmisc);
const JWKS = jose.createRemoteJWKSet(new URL(joseURL));
const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtVerify(theToken, JWKS)` Last line triggered err.

Comment: Post the token's header please.

Comment: token header, the part before the first `.`: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImJXOFpjTWpCQ25KWlMtaWJYNVVRRE5TdHZ4NCJ9`

Comment: There's no way that is the token from azure for which you get such an error.

Comment: That's why I believe it's something about Azure not **Jose**

Comment: Apologies, what I'm saying is that there's no way a token with alg RS256 in its header is the actual token that would result in the `Unsupported "alg" value for a JSON Web Key Set` error from remote jwks. Are you sure you're trying to verify a token that came from Azure and is meant to be introspected through JWT verification? It's most likely a JWE token meant to be consumed only by its issuer or you should decrypt its contents first. I have no way of knowing tho because you're very scarse on the actual token and jwks_uri values

Comment: Culprit found and fixed, I'll update in my post. Since your answer provides a less code and guided me through, it is chosen as Accepted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the below steps help to work around:**

Replace the `CERTIFICATE` keyword with `PUBLIC KEY` if you're using the public key or `PRIVATE KEY` if you're using the Private Key or `RSA PRIVATE KEY` if you are using RSA Private Key.

Also, the problem again occurs in the way we format the Public Key which requires begin and end lines, and line breaks at every 64 characters.

Refer [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/68#issuecomment-327455866) for more information.

Comment: As you can see there is no `CERTIFICATE` in my code. Believe there is something to do with Azure cloud policy particularly security. I've also tried [Jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) (see another Answer). Similar results: **works locally but not deployed to cloud**

Comment: Hello @Jeb50, Check by replacing the `var publickey` line of code to this: `var publickey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + await getMSPublicKey(vmisc) + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";`